# Make text appear to the right of a picture

Tags: html

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <img src="image.png"/>
    <div style="font-size: 100px;">Health And Wellbeing</div>
</div>
```

When I run this code, the words appear underneath the picture, is there any way to make the words appear to the right of the text?

Comment: do you want text above the image or overlay on image

Comment: I want the image to appear next to the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why your container div has `float: left;` in its styles, but you can use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to arrange the contents with more flexibility.

Here's a simple example:

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" />
    <div style="font-size: 100px;">Health And Wellbeing</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it simple? Just put `<img>` after the words...

```html
<div style="float: left;">
  <div style="font-size: 100px;">
    Health And Wellbeing
  </div>
  <img src="image.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make the question specific enough. But all the same, appreciated that you answered!

Comment: If it answers your question, pls accept it as the right answer

Comment: No, sorry. I meant for the words to appear next to the words, not above.